# Pagination for custom post types - url rewriting

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, pagination, rewrite-rules

I'm working with custom post type, that I want to paginate, here's part of code, initializing custom post type:

```
$args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array('title', 'page-attributes')
    );

    register_post_type( 'article', $args );
```

So, when url is `/article` I see first page of posts and there's no problem. `paginate_links()` function creates link to the second page `/article/page/2`, but it doesn't work - I have 404 error. [This](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/pagination-for-custom-post-types) topic describes absolutely the same problem, but solution by Mark doesn't work for me. If I add `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'artone')` for example, url `/article` doesn't work at all, only `/artone`.

As I understand, method of printing my articles doesn't matter. When I search something about this problem, I can see only advices about `query_posts`, `WP_query` and so on. But `is_archive()` becomes false and `is_404()` becomes true even before `header.php`, so I don't know, where the problem can be, maybe something in `functions.php`.

Also, even if I set default permalinks `?p=123` url `/?paged=2&post_type=article` doesn't work!

P.S. I don't forget flushing rewrite rules

Comment: @PieterGoosen what do you mean? I've said, that it doesn't matter, I can even not display posts at all and problem will exist. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I slightly misread the question. Did you hook your code to `init`?

Comment: @PieterGoosen do you mean post_type creation? of course, it works, there is also $labels and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Login as the admin in WordPress.

2.Go to the Settings tab.

3.Go to the Reading tab.

4.Change the Blog pages show at most from the default 10 to any number *less than 10. For example, 5.

5.Save the changes.

6.View the blog.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect! I've totally forgot about default posts_per_page, I think I should change it in some hook or set in interface. Thank you very much!

Comment: @lenden if this worked, then you are using a custom query of some kind.